# Memory requirement of C code

Tags: c++, c

Is there any way to know memory requirement of my C code?
For example I made C code of `int arrey[1000]`. so how much memory will it consume in RAM when running,can I know it with any code/tool without counting it manually?(system:Ubuntu)

Edited: Like for knowing the time we can give as time ./a.out which will give prefect time for program.

Comment: It will take `1000*sizeof(int)` + whatever process overhead is needed.

Comment: ...although, if the function where `arrey` is declared is recursive ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch your program, and at the same time, in a different terminal window, type

```
top
```

This will give you information about what's running on your system: CPU usage, memory, user, time...

Comment: but process is with very less running time(as I gave example of arrey) so I am not able to read it with top or system monitor.

Comment: Maybe you can add a pause on your process so it won't exit? A well-placed `cin << a;` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

To find the memory requirement for the array you would find the size of the entire array using the *sizeof* function:

```
cout << "bytes used: " << sizeof(arrey) << endl;
```

To find the memeory of each element:

```
cout << "byte per element: " << sizeof(int) << endl;
```

Comment: I'm quite sure your second example returns the number of elements, not the size of each.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Fixed it

Comment: Nitpick: `sizeof` is not a function.  Also, better to use `sizeof array[0]` than `sizeof int` to find the size of an element.

Comment: Because sizeof has a special behaviour with char arrays, it returns the size of a char* insteaf of returning the size of the array. It even issues compiler warnings.

Comment: No, neither in C nor in C++. If you pass an array to `sizeof`, you get `number_of_elements * bytes_per_element`, regardless of type. If you pass a pointer (most likely because the array decayed to a pointer to the first element as a function argument), you get the size of a pointer, of course. Out of curiosity, which compiler behaves otherwise and warns?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the code and you have comppiled it, you can use `valgrind` . This console tool will print a Heap Summary, and how many of the memory allocated has been lost with the memory fails and the position of them on code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Linux commands  to get statistics about system memory usage:

```
$ free
...
$ cat /proc/meminfo
...
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ps` command, you can get the amount of memory pages allocated by your process. It is not a perfect index; if you want more precision, use a memory profiler, such as *gperftools*.

Answer (score 0):

just use sizeof `cout<<sizeof(arrey);`

Answer (score 0):

From inside your own application, you could read (sequentially) `/proc/self/statm`, `/proc/self/maps` etc. Read more about the `/proc` filesystem in the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page.

(Bounding the memory consumption by static analysis of your C source code is in general intractable or impossible)

Answer (score -3):

1000 * 4 = 4000, on the stack.

Comment: 1. `int arrey[1000]` says nothing about where the variable is being allocated; it may be a local variable, a global or even a member of a `struct` (which could be allocated on the heap). 2. `int` is not 4 bytes everywhere (although on platforms where Ubuntu runs it is so).